# IE7: How to set the "class" attribute for a dynamically created element in javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, class, internet-explorer-7

It appears that this:

```
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.setAttribute("class", "check");
```

doesn't work in IE7, that is the styles specified by that class in css are not applied. It works fine in IE8, FF etc. Is there a way of setting the class in IE7 or do I have to do:

```
img.style.border = ....
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just:

```
img.className = "check";
```

Internet Explorer can get really upset when you try to use "setAttribute()" sometimes. I don't have a VM running but if you've got your heart set on using "setAttribute()" then you might try:

```
img.setAttribute("className", "check");
```

but I don't know that that will work.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you need to use:

```
img.className = "check";
```